# Extension attribute on admin page

Tags: magento2, admin, extension-attributes

I've successfully created a new field on the frontend with an `extension_attribute` by [this documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html).

My problem is that where should I hook the extension attributes on the admin page?

The shipping method is set by `Magento_Sales/order/create/scripts.js` with the `Adminorder.setShippingMethod` mehod.

But this is a prototype file, I can not hook on it with mixin, since it has no return value.

How can I add/get the `extension_attributes` with my value?

Answer (score 0):

I need to use the `window.order` in my javascript file instead of `AdminOrder`. It created from `form.js`.